# Dynamically increment lists to Python function

Tags: python, pandas, xml, list

I am trying to implement a function that receives a dynamically number of node names from `*args` and concatenates it to my `xmltodict.parse()`. Is it possible?
Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve where `*args` would pass 3 arguments (first, second and third node):

```
def parseXML(xml, *args):
    xd = xmltodict.parse(xml)['First_Node']['Second_Node']['Third_Node']
    df = pd.json_normalize(xd)
    
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
def parseXML(xml, *args):
    xd = xmltodict.parse(xml)
    for arg in args:
        xd = xd[arg]
    df = pd.json_normalize(xd)  
    return df
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Out of curiosity, how is it that xd[arg] doesn't override the xd variable after each iteration?

Comment: It does override. Its like a dict  x = {'a': 'b':{'c': 1}}}. If you do x = x['a'] it's just going to override and set x to {'b' : {'c':1}}, and if you do x=x['b'] it's going to override to {'c': 1}. Your parse(xml) is just a deep dict which you are going one step inside each iteration.